# How to get data from parent to child table multiple times in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I've got 3 tables and models: `City`, `Club` and `Event`.

Their relationship is that `Event` is a child of `Club` and `Club` is a child of `City`.

I know how to retrieve data from a child to a parent but how can I do this from a parent to a child?

My problem is that I don't know how to code this complex request. Also I don't know what to do in case that every request would be empty.

```php
{{ $cityView->club->event->name }}
```

But even `$cityView->club` is empty.

---

#### What I've tried

I tried to declare another variable and by using it to get club's `id` where `id = club_id(from city)` and then do the same for `Event` since I need to take out event's data.

So here is how my method looks like inside my controller:

```
public function cityView($id)
{
    $cityView = City::find($id);

    $club = Club::get()->where('city_id', $id);
    $clubid = $club->id;

    $event = Event::get()->where('club_id', $clubid);

    dump($cityView);
    dump($event);

    dd($clubid);

    return view('frontend/cityView', ['cityView' => $cityView], ['club' => $club]);
}
```

Right now, my dump on `$clubid` gets me the correct attributes (whole `clubs` with `city_id` same as I wanted but `events` gives back 0 results).

I've added data for `events`, so I'm sure there are `events` connected to one of those `clubs`.

[image: Screenshot of dumps]

I don't know how to make a valid query.

Comment: you can use belongsTo relationship here. This may help https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse

Comment: From your screenshot it seems that you have values in your **$eventId** not **$clubId**. Can you clarify it?

Comment: Author, you need to read the documentation more as this is super simple and it is beautifully explained in the documentation... You are trying to use _vanilla_ PHP rather than Laravel... Also, **NEVER** do `Model::get()->wheres` as that is 0% performant... you could be getting 100k records with `get()` and that will use a lot of memory for no reason and will be super slow... then you filter the collection with a `where`, iteration the whole collection, again not performant... so, invert them, `Model::where('column', 123)->get();`... And for view, you have to do a full array, not 2 arrays...

Comment: @matiaslauriti Thank you for your tips, I didnt know about it earlier, I will be using it from now on :)!

Answer (score 2):

> Their relationship is that event is child of club and club is child of city.

So:

- `Event` *belongsTo* `Club`
- `Club` *belongsTo* `City`

In these models, you should have these relationships:

```php
// Event.php

public function club()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Club::class);
}
```

```php
// Club.php

public function city()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\City::class);
}

public function events()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Event::class);
    // hasOne instead of hasMany if there will always be one Event. Also, the method name should me singular in this case, but this is just a naming convention
}
```

```php
// City.php

public function clubs()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Club::class);
    // hasOne instead of hasMany if there will always be one Club. Also, the method name should me singular in this case, but this is just a naming convention
}
```

Here, I'm assuming that:

- a `City` can have multiple `Club`
- a `Club` can have multiple `Event`

That's why I used `hasMany` to define the parent -> children relationship.

In this scenario, you must loop through the children, since there can be many of them (use a `foreach`).

**If this is not the case, don't use `hasMany`, but `hasOne`.** As the name suggests, `hasOne` define a relation where, for instance, a `City` can only have one `Club`.

If you do this, you'll be able to `{{ $cityView->club->event->name }}`.

Comment: Thank you for this. Even tho I made as you showed, I still cannot get any However, I still cannot use this $cityView->club->event->name }}.
The error is: Property [event] does not exist on this collection instance.

I check if its true, but first club in array got many events. ( i changed all of model classes for single target, its easier for me to move around it.

Comment: You have this error because you are returning many clubs, so you have a collection (`hasMany` would do the same).You should first rename your `$club` variable to `$clubs` to be more accurate, then you'll have to loop through each of them with `foreach($clubs as $club){ $club->event; //is available here }`.

Comment: I made just like you said, foreach($clubs as $club)
{{$club->name}}
endforeach

I just wanted to see name first if it actually works but still got error: Attempt to read property "name" on null

Did it also with foreach($this->clubs as $club)
{{$club->name}}
endforeach

With same error. :_:

Cant use more than 1 Shit+2 sign in comment but i didnt forget about them in foreach loops

Answer (score 0):

When you use get() to fetch your data it returns you an object. That means your **$club** is an object of multiple collections. Hence, you cannot access **$club->id** directly.

Rather than that you can implement a foreach loop like this to access the id-

```
$cityView = City::find($id);
$club = Club::get()->where('city_id',$id);
foreach($club as $c){ //this loop will continue for each instance of the club
    $clubid = $c->id;   //this will return a specific id of a club
    $event = Event::get()->where('club_id',$clubid); //this will return all the events of that particular club
}
```

However I strongly suggest you to use Eloquent Model Relationship feature here. This may help you- https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse.

Comment: You suggestion (last one) is correct, but the first part is not, as `Club::get()` is the same as `all()` and then `where` applies to the collection, so it is 0% performant. You should not be doing so.

Comment: Thank you for your time and answear, however, I tried both methods you mentioned and both cases $event is empty, its not because of db tho since, i added events for clubs which are in array.